# Get rid of quality issues when modifying a PDF with ImageMagick

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

Our goal is it to take a user uploaded PDF and put a "stamp" (a box with a background color + text) on the top left corner. The "stamp" part works well, but as soon as we pass the PDF through ImageMagick we immediately get quality problems - especially when the original PDF already had some kind of artefacts.

This is a screenshot from my source PDF (black areas added for privacy reasons).
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6271307/Screen%20Shot%202016-09-22%20at%2015.18.49.png
You can see the quality isn't very good because it was scanned by a copy machine.

After being processed by ImageMagick the result looks like this:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6271307/Screen%20Shot%202016-09-22%20at%2015.19.15.png

This is the call that is being made:

```
'/usr/bin/convert' +profile '*' -compress jpeg -quality 90 -density 180 -pointsize 10 -fill 'rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.75)' -stroke 'rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.75)' -draw 'rectangle 40,20,491,100' -stroke '#000000' -font Courier -draw "text 48,47 'Vermittlernummer Gesellschaft'" -draw "text 48,81 '70_202_3297'" mysource.pdf mytarget.pdf
```

- If I leave out the "-compress jpeg -quality 90" parameters the result looks the same, it's just a bit bigger in file size.
- If I leave out the "-density 180" parameter the result just looks a lot worse

What options of ImageMagick can help me to get a better result?

Answer (score 0):

Try first converting your pdf to a png.  The reason I say this is because I downloaded your .png image:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6271307/Screen%20Shot%202016-09-22%20at%2015.18.49.png

and ran your code:

```
  convert -density 180  +profile '*' -compress jpeg -quality 90 -pointsize 10 -fill 'rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.75)' -stroke 'rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.75)' -draw 'rectangle 40,20,491,100' -stroke '#000000' -font Courier -draw "text 48,47 'Vermittlernummer Gesellschaft'" -draw "text 48,81 '70_202_3297'" test.png mytarget.png
```

and got this result:

[image]

Which looks good to me.  I outputted a .png using your code but the pdf looks just as good -- StackOverflow doesn't seem to allow pdf uploads.

Let me know if that doesn't work!

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I tried to convert the PDF to PNG in a first step but then already I get those problems. So the issue seems not be related to the format that is written but rather at the "reading" part.

Comment: did you try setting the -density in the conversion?  Can you post your code in a comment or update your question?